# Is there a way I can change the width of text which is on second line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiline

I have a requirement where I want to reduce the width of the second line of text dynamically,

```
this is first line text
this is second line text
```

so the above Text I want to look like this

```
this is first line text
this is ...
```

The rest of the space I want to use to some other icons on hover on the div/span.

Currently I rely on reducing the width of the span, I have explored ellipses and line-clamp properties but this combination works for both the lines not on second or last line. so the result I get is something like this -

```
this is first
line text ...
```

Here is a js fiddle for what I have tried -
https://jsfiddle.net/htpxrg90/4/

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `:nth-child()` in CSS could be useful. If only you'd posted what you tried so I could test it out.

Comment: let me create a fiddle and post it here.

Comment: This [answer on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/5217142) covers creating code snippets in the post instead of using an external site, and is more convenient for readers trying to assist you.

Comment: Here is the fiddle of what I have tried https://jsfiddle.net/htpxrg90/4/  @traktor

Comment: The fiddle does not create two lines of output for "This is the first line text, this is the second line text.".  Although perhaps an "X-Y" problem, I suggest you set up the conditions of having two lines before continuing, or update the question with details of what you expect to achieve from a technical description  of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Add below css to the 2nd line,you can set specific width so that u can achieve this

```
.secondline {
   width: 100px;
   display: -webkit-box;
   webkit-line-clamp: 1;
   webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: there is no separate element where I can give this css class. Here is a fiddle of what I have tried. https://jsfiddle.net/htpxrg90/4/